# Problems with Failure in Testing Notebooks

Tags: bugs, front-end, testing-and-verification

This always fails the test:

```
Failure["General", <|"MessageTemplate" -> "`1`", "MessageParameters" -> {foo}|>]
```

While this passes as expected:

```
Failure["General", <|"MessageTemplate" :> "`1`", "MessageParameters" -> {1}|>  ]
```

[image]

What do I do wrong? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Issue confirmed by WRI support, will edit the header later.